# how can I assign number type to object type at all in typescript?

Tags: javascript, typescript

there're some things I don't understand about js and typescript.

Here is what I understand.

1) There're primitive and non-primitive types in typescript(primitive - boolean, stirng, number, null, undefined ) and non-primitive(object,array). so when someone says everything is an object in js , he seems to be wrong right? (That's my first question).

2)

```js
var objectEx1: Object;
var objectEx2: {};
var anyEx: any;
var numEx: number;
var stringEx: string;

objectEx1 = numEx; // why does this work?
numEx = objectEx1; // why doesn't this work?

console.log(objectEx1, numEx);
```

Comment: The idea of "everything is an object in JavaScript" is derived from the idea that primitive types are automatically converted to an object as soon as you 'use' them. So something like this string: "This is a string" can be 'used' immediately as an object like so: `"This is a string".length` - hence the primitive string type is converted to an object. Try it in the console right now.

Comment: I suggest to start with the [Mozilla documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Primitive). Don't miss the _"wrapper objects"_ section.

Comment: From [docs](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html): "variables of type Object... allow you to assign any value to them"

Comment: And do not use `Object` but `object`. https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-files/do-s-and-don-ts.html

Comment: I tried var a = "good"; then console.log(typeof a) it gave me string. then I tried var a = new String("good"). then console.log(typeof a) it gave me object. so @RandyCasburn I think if you were right, it would give me object type for both scenarios.

Comment: @NikaKhurashvili - that doesn't make my point wrong, in fact it makes my point for me. Read [the docs for typeof](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/typeof) - the first line says: "The typeof operator returns a string indicating the type of the unevaluated operand." The most import part? **unevaluated operand**. Reread my comment and you will see I made a point of saying in quotes "as you 'use' them" - hence they become **evaluated** and are converted to objects.

Comment: @NikaKhurashvili That is why if you ask for the `.constructor` property of `a="good"` and `a = new String('good')` both will return String.